# Getting values from a hash by order defined in another list

Tags: perl

Looking for a way, how to get the values from a hash, in an order defined by another list.

The "demo" code (real values are different):

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my $href = {
    'Long one' => 'v1',
    'xxx two'  => 'v2',
    'another3' => 'v3',
    'xfour'    => 'v4',
    'some5'    => undef,
};

#keys from the $href in defined order
my @order = ('Long one', 'xfour', 'nono', 'another3', 'some5', 'xxx two');

#in the real code:
#my $href = some_sub(......);  my @order = another_sub(....);

#cleanup the @order form undefined values
@order = grep { exists $href->{$_} && defined $href->{$_} } @order;

#my input
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    #filter out nonexistent keys and undefined values
    my @defined_data = grep { exists $href->{$_} && defined $href->{$_} } split '/';

    my $str = "xx";
    $str = join('/',
               map { $href->{$_} }  some_my_sort(@defined_data)
    ) if @defined_data;

    say $str;
}

sub some_my_sort {
    my(@list) = @_;

    # "somewhat"sort the @list in order defined by @order
    # haven't any idea how to do this :(

    # __HERE NEED HELP__ to sort the @list, to the order defined in the @order

    #and get only first two values. if exists only one value, return only one
    if($#list > 0) {
        return ($list[0], $list[1]);
    }
    else {
        return($list[0]);
    }
}

__DATA__
another3/some5/Long one/xfour/xxx two
xxx two/blabla/some5/another3/xfour
some5
notexists/some5/xxx two/Long one
some5/another3
```

for the above input want get the next output:

```
v1/v4
v4/v3
xx
v1/v2
v3
```

Form @ikegami solution:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my $href = { 'Long one' => 'v1', 'xxx two'  => 'v2', 'another3' => 'v3', 'xfour'    => 'v4', 'some5'    => undef, };
my @order = ('Long one', 'xfour', 'nono', 'another3', 'some5', 'xxx two');
@order = grep { exists $href->{$_} && defined $href->{$_} } @order;

my %order = map { $order{$_} => $_ } 0..$#order;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @keys = grep { defined $href->{$_} } split '/';
    @keys = sort { $order{$a} <=> $order{$b} } @keys;
    splice(@keys, 2) if @keys > 2;
    @keys = 'xx' if !@keys;
    say join '/', @{$href}{ @keys };
}
```

get the next - error - and don't really understand why:

```
Global symbol "%order" requires explicit package name at ike line 8.
Execution of ike aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Can you try to explain a little better?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `$order[$_]` in the `map`. There's also another small problem. Both are fixed in the Answer. I'm really off my game :( Sorry!!

Comment: @ikegami ;) np, thank you very much anyway - i'm happy to learning new things. Still throwing runtime error: Use of uninitialized value within @ keys in join or string at ike line 15, <DATA> line 3.

Comment: That's the "other small problem" I mentioned. See the Answer. What's there is actually tested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After defining @order, define %order_h:

```
my %order_h;
my $i = 0;
$order_h{$_} = $i++ for @order;
```

Then, instead of the comment about sorting, add this line:

```
@list = sort { $order_h{$a} <=> $order_h{$b} } @list;
```

---

Here's a cleaned-up version of the entire code:

```
my %order = map { $order[$_] => $_ } 0..$#order;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @keys = grep { defined $href->{$_} } split '/';
    @keys = sort { $order{$a} <=> $order{$b} } @keys;
    splice(@keys, 2) if @keys > 2;
    say join '/', @keys ? @{$href}{ @keys } : 'xx';
}
```

Comment: @ikegami - cleaned up, but throwing error, and don't understatand why - see my edited qst.

Comment: @ikegami - YES! Thank you - now i'm start to study - how it is works. ;)